# Iterating Through Multiple Databases with Information Schema

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

`Information Schema` only pulls data for the database that I am using.

Is there a way to make it search multiple databases?

I'm basically trying to examine all columns, from all tables, in all databases without having to run it once for each database.

Comment: You can just `union all` the results from `db1.sys.tables` and `db2.sys.tables`. If you don't know the names of the databases you need dynamic SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no instance-level metadata views that have this information.

You can iterate over all the databases in a single batch, however.  See eg:
[A reliable and flexible replacement for sp_MSforeachdb](https://sqlblog.org/2020/08/04/reliable-flexible-replacement-sp_msforeachdb)